# i want to create a bar chart of array with given user inputs

Tags: java, arrays

1. You are given a number n, representing the size of array a.
2. You are given n numbers, representing elements of array a.
3. You are required to print a bar chart representing value of arr a.

A bar chart of asterisks representing value of array a

SAMPLE INPUT:-
5
3
1
0
7
5

SAMPLE OUTPUT:-

[image]

I  tried  getting this input from this approach can anyone help me? What should I do to get the same?

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // write your code here
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int x = arr[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
                System.out.print("*" + "\n");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75039665/16034206). Very similar question

Answer (score 0):

A 2D array of chars may be used to represent the graph field to "draw" vertical bars `char[][] map`.

The dimensions of this array are:

- height: the maximal number in the input `arr`
- width: the number of columns (`arr.length`) plus an empty column between each asterisk bar, that makes: `2 * arr.length - 1`

*it may be better to have a parameter `space` between the bars and calculate the width of map accordingly:* `(space + 1) * arr.length - space`

Populate each row of the map with default whitespaces (maybe using `Arrays.fill`).

Nested loops: Fill asterisks in the relevant columns from bottom to top, calculate indexes of the columns with regard to `space` parameter.

Loop: Print each row of `map` converting the `char[]` into String.

Coding is left for exercise.

Answer (score 0):

```
//finding largest element in an array
int l = arr[0];
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    if(arr[i] > l)
        l = arr[i];
}
//traversing using largest element as no. of rows
for(int i = l; i > 0; i--) {
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if(i <= arr[j])
            System.out.print("*       ");
        else
            System.out.print("        ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```